# load list item in CSOM

Tags: 2013, development, csom, visual-studio-2013

Please guide me with code sample to get list item in CSOM c# for all fields

I loaded the client context for list item and only the title field is retrieved

Other fields like the choice field are not retrieved.

Error

> The property or field has not been initialized

Please help me!

Comment: Please try to post your code to can help you faster

Comment: can you share which all type field you want to retrieve, text and choice field?

Comment: The list has three fields with different data type, i am able to get only the title field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify following code to fetch all fields of your item:

```
        var list = _clientContext.Web.GetListByUrl(<ListUrl>);
        var query = new CamlQuery
        {
            ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>Home</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
        };
        var listItems = list.GetItems(query);
        _clientContext.Load(listItems);
        _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

*GetListByUrl()* is extension method from Office PnP Core library - if you do not use it, you can replace it with following code:

```
_clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle()
```

In provided sample I was filtering by Title field - if you specify your query as follows:

```
var query = new CamlQuery();
```

you will fetch all items and all of their fields.

Hope it will help:)

**UDPATE**

Getting items with IDs only can be done this way:

```
        var query2 = new CamlQuery();
        var listItems2 = list.GetItems(query2);
        _clientContext.Load(listItems2, items => items.Include(i => i.Id).Where(i => i.Id == 1));
        _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Where statement can be removed if you want to get all items with theirs' ids. This approach is a bit different than previous one - I do not use ViewXml of CamlQuery, but output is exactly the same.

Comment: Two concerns I'm having: why  you use value in viewxml, 2.how can I get only list item with it's ID?

Comment: I used ViewXml to limit result of the query to single element matching my requirements.